# How can I implement "Read more" in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How I can add 'Read mode' or 'Continue' for any article where this 'read more' will appear after short description of the article. Do I need to save the short description in database in separately?? Or Is there any way to fix it the number of character will appear in the home feed and generate 'read more' link dynamically ??

Comment: What do _you_ mean by "read more"? The principle has many implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Well This is not the best way but its a easy work around you just have to hide the div with the full content on page load and show the div with less content and then on button click show the div with full content and hide the div with less content while changing the button text and hiding dots.

CSS

```
 #ReadLess {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div id="ReadMore">
     @Model.DESCRIPTION.Substring(0, 100);
  </div>
  <div id="ReadLess">
      @Model.DESCRIPTION;
  </div>
  <span id="dots">...</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

JavaScript

```
 function myFunction() {
    var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
    var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    var ReadMore = document.getElementById("ReadMore");
    var ReadLess = document.getElementById("ReadLess");

    if (ReadMore.style.display === "none") {
        dots.style.display = "inline";
        ReadLess.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read More";
        ReadMore.style.display = "inline";
    } else {
        dots.style.display = "none";
        ReadMore.style.display = "none";
        btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
        ReadLess.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not store the short description separatly as you would duplicate data in database and have no real gain in doing so. The short text can be obtained easily with String. Substr. There are many JavaScript libraries that let you automatically handle this for you like this one for jQuery https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the string in your razor views like so ;

// let say you want to show first 100 chars of your article, and have a link to full article,

```
@myarticle.body.Substring(0,100) @Html.ActionLink("Read More", "Details", new {Id=myarticle.id})
```

if you want to show your article  in same page after clicking Read More you may get complete article via an ajax call/.

Comment: This would only work well if your `body` has no markup tags and you don't care if a word is split in the middle

Comment: How can I handle situation where body less than 100 symbols so we don't need to add action link ?

Answer (score 0):

You could save the short description as a separate column, but I wouldn't try to duplicate data (as also [slvperron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28470547/95976) said above). It depends on your requirements really.

Some news sites have:

```
News {
title : String, // displayed in heading
summary : String, // summarises the article, displayed in bold or other bg
content : String, // the rest of the article
}
```

This setup gives more flexibility with (HTML) markup. A simple `substring(0,100)` could break a markup tag somewhere in the middle, and force the browser to render incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to display a one line summary and jquery to toggle between it and the full text version

html

```
<div class="summary text">@Model.YourReallyLongTextProperty</div>
<a href="#">more</a>
```

css

```
.summary {
  width:250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Script

```
$('a').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).prev('.text');
  text.toggleClass('summary');
  if(text.hasClass('summary')) {
    $(this).text('more');
  } else {
    $(this).text('less');
  }
});
```

[Refer fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84q1pdeL/)